# Spark job Killed: /tmp/spark-driver.log does not exist

Tags: pyspark, cloudera

I am running a Spark job in Cloudera Data Science Workbench. Sometimes it runs okay, but sometimes it fails with this error:

`log4j:ERROR setFile(null,true) call failed.
    java.io.FileNotFoundException: /tmp/spark-driver.log (Permission denied)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.open0(Native Method)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.open(FileOutputStream.java:270)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:213)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:133)
    at org.apache.log4j.FileAppender.setFile(FileAppender.java:294)
    at org.apache.log4j.FileAppender.activateOptions(FileAppender.java:165)`

Upon checking, the files exists:

    `cdsw@jw4l5ll7jj0l3bcy:~$ ls /tmp/spark-driver.log
    /tmp/spark-driver.log`

I've already looked at the Spark UI log and can't find any other error. This is the only error we found. Already desperate for answers. Any leads would be appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The error stack-trace states permission issues for the /tmp directory on your machines. You can refer to the following [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49935575/5742662) by Michail N. I hope it solves your issues.